# Using reduce function to retrieve a value from a call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a simple function that uses `reduce` native method in order to get back the value of a called function.
Here's my code:

```js
const test = (...ps) =>
    ps.reduce((prev, next) =>
        parameter => prev(parameter)
    )
```

I am calling it using the following line:

```js
test(() => 42)
```

I would obtain the return value of the called function because `prev` is the unique value of `ps` array, but it works only when I define another function using `next` parameter.

Expected result: `42`

Current result: `() => 42`

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: please add the missing data and the wanted result.

Comment: Please post complete, syntactically valid code

Comment: "*prev is the unique value of ps array*" - what? No. `prev` is the accumulator variable, the return value of the previous reducer application. What are you trying to do?

Comment: added missing data and wanted result, code corrected, it runs and it is syntactically valid, yes it is the accumulator variable I expect to be equal to the first element of the array (which is ps[0]) and ps shouldn't have other elements

Comment: @blurstream The `(prev, next) =>
        parameter => prev(parameter)` callback is not even called on an array with only a single element, since you were not passing an initial accumulator value.

Comment: What you're missing is that `reduce` will return the value returned by its callback in its final iteration. Your callback returns a function (`parameter => prev(parameter)`) in every iteration, so that's what `reduce` returns.

Comment: where is the value of `42` coming from? please add the array as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz The array is `ps`, i.e. the arguments passed to `test`, i.e. `[ () => 42 ]`.

Comment: if the element of the array for reduce has only one element, this element is returned without calling the callback of reduce. you need to specify a start value, then a single item array is calling the callback. btw, you do not call the paramter function ...